# How to slim down a Fat Interface without breaking the Decorator pattern?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, decorator

In my C++ library code I'm using an abstract base class as an interface to all different kinds of I/O-capable objects.  It currently looks like this:

```
// All-purpose interface for any kind of object that can do I/O
class IDataIO
{
public:
   // basic I/O calls
   virtual ssize_t Read(void * buffer, size_t size) = 0;
   virtual ssize_t Write(const void * buffer, size_t size) = 0;

   // Seeking calls (implemented to return error codes
   // for I/O objects that can't actually seek)
   virtual result_t Seek(ssize_t offset, int whence) = 0;
   virtual ssize_t GetCurrentSeekPosition() const = 0;
   virtual ssize_t GetStreamLength() const = 0;

   // Packet-specific calls (implemented to do nothing
   // for I/O objects that aren't packet-oriented)
   virtual const IPAddressAndPort & GetSourceOfLastReadPacket() const = 0;
   virtual result_t SetPacketSendDestination(const IPAddressAndPort & iap) = 0;
};
```

This works pretty well -- I have various concrete subclasses for TCP, UDP, files, memory buffers, SSL, RS232, stdin/stdout, and so on, and I'm able to write I/O-agnostic routines that can be used in conjunction with any of them.

I also have various [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) classes that take ownership of an existing `IDataIO` object and serve as a behavior-modifying front-end to that object.  These decorator classes are useful because a single decorator class be used to can modify/enhance the behavior of any kind of `IDataIO` object.  Here's a simple (toy) example:

```
/** Example decorator class:  This object wraps any given
  * child IDataIO object, such that all data going out is
  * obfuscated by applying an XOR transformation to the bytes,
  * and any data coming in is de-obfuscated the same way.
  */
class XorDataIO : public IDataIO
{
public:
   XorDataIO(IDataIO * child) : _child(child) {/* empty */}
   virtual ~XorDataIO() {delete _child;}

   virtual ssize_t Read(void * buffer, size_t size)
   {
      ssize_t ret = _child->Read(buffer, size);
      if (ret > 0) XorData(buffer, ret);
      return ret;
   }

   virtual ssize_t Write(const void * buffer, size_t size)
   {
      XorData(buffer, size);   // const-violation here, but you get the idea
      return _child->Write(buffer, size);
   }

   virtual result_t Seek(ssize_t offset, int whence) {return _child->Seek(offset, whence);}
   virtual ssize_t GetCurrentSeekPosition() const    {return _child->GetCurrentSeekPosition();}
   virtual ssize_t GetStreamLength() const           {return _child->GetStreamLength();}

   virtual const IPAddressAndPort & GetSourceOfLastReadPacket() const      {return _child->GetSourceOfLastReadPacket();}
   virtual result_t SetPacketSendDestination(const IPAddressAndPort & iap) {return _child->SetPacketSendDestination(iap);}

private:
   IDataIO * _child;
};
```

This is all well and good, but what's bothering me is that my `IDataIO` class looks like an example of a [fat interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084139/what-is-a-fat-interface) -- for example, a `UDPSocketDataIO` class will never be able to implement the `Seek()`, `GetCurrentSeekPosition()`, and `GetStreamLength()` methods, while a `FileDataIO` class will never be able to implement the `GetSourceOfLastReadPacket()` and `SetPacketSendDestination()` methods.  So both classes are forced to implement those methods as stubs that just do nothing and return an error code -- which works, but it's ugly.

To solve the problem, I'd like to break out the `IDataIO` interface into separate chunks, like this:

```
// The bare-minimum interface for any object that we can
// read bytes from, or write bytes to (e.g. TCP or RS232)
class IDataIO
{
public:
   virtual ssize_t Read(void * buffer, size_t size) = 0;
   virtual ssize_t Write(const void * buffer, size_t size) = 0;
};

// A slightly extended interface for objects (e.g. files
// or memory-buffers) that also allows us to seek to a
// specified offset within the data-stream.
class ISeekableDataIO : public IDataIO
{
public:
   virtual result_t Seek(ssize_t offset, int whence) = 0;
   virtual ssize_t GetCurrentSeekPosition() const = 0;
   virtual ssize_t GetStreamLength() const = 0;
};

// A slightly extended interface for packet-oriented
// objects (e.g. UDP sockets)
class IPacketDataIO : public IDataIO
{
public:
   virtual const IPAddressAndPort & GetSourceOfLastReadPacket() const = 0;
   virtual result_t SetPacketSendDestination(const IPAddressAndPort & iap) = 0;
};
```

.... so now I can subclass `UDPSocketDataIO` from the `IPacketDataIO` sub-interface, and subclass `FileDataIO` from the `ISeekableDataIO` interface, while `TCPSocketDataIO` can still subclass directly from `IDataIO`, and so on.  That way each type of I/O object presents the interface only to the functionality it can actually support, and nobody has to implement no-op/stub versions of methods that are irrelevant to what they do.

So far, so good, but the problem that arises at this point is with the decorator classes -- what interface should my `XorDataIO` subclass inherit from in this scenario?  I suppose I could write a `XorDataIO`, a `XorSeekableDataIO`, and a `XorPacketDataIO`, so that all three types of interface can be fully decorated, but I'd really rather not -- that seems like a lot of redundancy/overhead, particularly if I have multiple different adapter classes already and I don't want to multiple their numbers further by a factor of three.

Is there some well-known clever/elegant way to address this problem, such that I can have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most clever/elegant way to address this problem, but after some more reflection, here's what I came up with:

1) Use "virtual inheritance" for the two extended interfaces:

```
class ISeekableDataIO : public virtual IDataIO {...}
class IPacketDataIO   : public virtual IDataIO {...}
```

2) Create a `DecoratorDataIO` class that inherits from both of those interfaces, and passes all method calls through to the appropriate ones on the child `IDataIO` object, if possible:

```
class DecoratorDataIO : public IPacketDataIO, public ISeekableDataIO
{
public:
   DecoratorDataIO(const IDataIO * childIO)
      : _childIO(childIO)
      , _seekableChildIO(dynamic_cast<ISeekableDataIO *>(childIO))
      , _packetChildIO(dynamic_cast<IPacketDataIO *>(childIO))
   {
      // empty
   }

   virtual ~DecoratorDataIO() {delete _childIO;}

   // IDataIO interface implementation
   virtual ssize_t Read(void * buffer, size_t size) {return _childIO() ? _childIO()->Read(buffer, size) : -1;}
   virtual ssize_t Write(const void * buffer, size_t size) {return _childIO() ? _childIO()->Write(buffer, size) : -1;}

   // ISeekableDataIO interface implementation
   virtual result_t Seek(ssize_t offset, int whence) {return _seekableChildIO ? _seekableChildIO->Seek(offset, whence) : B_ERROR;}
   virtual ssize_t GetCurrentSeekPosition() const {return _seekableChildIO ? _seekableChildIO->GetCurrentSeekPosition() : -1;}
   virtual ssize_t GetStreamLength() const {return _seekableChildIO ? _seekableChildIO->GetStreamLength() : -1;}

   // IPacketDataIO interface implementation
   virtual const IPAddressAndPort & GetSourceOfLastReadPacket() const {return _packetChildIO ? _packetChildIO->GetSourceOfLastReadPacket() : GetDefaultObjectForType<IPAddressAndPort>();}
   virtual const IPAddressAndPort & GetPacketSendDestination() const  {return _packetChildIO ? _packetChildIO->GetPacketSendDestination()  : GetDefaultObjectForType<IPAddressAndPort>();}

private:
   IDataIO * _childIO;
   ISeekableDataIO * _seekableChildIO;
   IPacketDataIO   * _packetChildIO;
};
```

3) Now my decorator classes can just subclass DecoratorDataIO and override whichever methods they choose to (calling up to the superclass implementation of the method as necessary):

```
class XorDataIO : public DecoratorDataIO
{  
public:
   XorDataIO(IDataIO * child) : DecoratorDataIO(child) {/* empty */}

   virtual ssize_t Read(void * buffer, size_t size)
   {  
      ssize_t ret = DecoratorDataIO::Read(buffer, size);
      if (ret > 0) XorData(buffer, ret);
      return ret;
   }

   virtual ssize_t Write(const void * buffer, size_t size)
   {  
      XorData(buffer, size);   // const-violation here, but you get the idea
      return DecoratorDataIO::Write(buffer, size);
   }
};
```

This approach accomplishes my goals, and if there is some ugliness (i.e. dynamic_cast<>), at least it is contained within the `DecoratorDataIO` class and not exposed to all the decorator subclasses.