# C++: Issue with clearing a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector

**EDIT:** It seems this is a problem with using `memset` on my struct, instead clearing the vector. Thanks to all that have provided advice!

---

I'm attempting to clear my vector of Subject objects (my own defined class) called people. The vector sits in a struct (pQA) and is defined as the following:

```
typedef struct _FSTRUCT_
{
    const char * filePath;
    std::vector<Subject> people;
    long srcImageWidth;
    long srcImageHeight;
    STRUCT_CONFIG_PARAMS * configParam;
    unsigned char * imageBuf;
    int imageBufLen;
} STRUCT_FSTRUCT;
```

I am creating the pQA struct by:

```
STRUCT_FSTRUCT *pQA = NULL;
pQA = new STRUCT_FSTRUCT();
memset(pQA,0,sizeof(STRUCT_FSTRUCT));
```

I populate 'people' with data by using the Subject class' set methods. This is all fine. What I am wanting to do is then reset 'people', i.e. clear out all data and set the size to 0. I call the below method:

```
int ResetFaceCollection()
{
    if (!pQA->people.empty())
    {
        pQA->people.clear();
    }
}
```

The `clear()` line throws a debug assertion failed error message which states "Expression: vector iterators incompatible".

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with Subject's destructor:

```
Subject::~Subject(void)
{
}
```

I'm not using any pointers, so from what I've gathered, the destructor looks OK. I have, of course, defined the destructor in my .h file also `~Subject(void);`.

I'm a bit lost as to why this is happening. Can anyone provide some insight?

I apologize if I'm omitted any necessary code, can update upon request!

Comment: `_MYSTRUCT_` is a reserved identifier

Comment: why use a weirdly named struct with only a vector inside? Just use the vector directly. Also nothing that seems wrong in the code you showed, you might want to post a bit more. **Edit:** Oh and checking if it's empty is superfluous, `.clear()` is a noop anyways if it's empty so just call it without that if.

Comment: I omitted the rest of the variables, will add in now. :/

Comment: Without more code this question cannot be answered

Comment: Likely: `pQA` isn't a valid pointer. (The `typedef struct X...` roundabout is a C-ism which is completely unnecessary in C++.)

Comment: I think you may be right, @molbdnilo... EDIT: okay nope.

Comment: `std::vector<Subject>().swap(pQA->people);` seems to work fine?

Comment: @LBran That doesn't indicate that `pQA` was valid, only that it points to writable memory. How are you creating and using `pQA` before this point?

Comment: @molbdnilo - I am creating pQA by: `STRUCT_SPID_QA *pQA = NULL;
 pQA = new STRUCT_SPID_QA();
 memset(pQA,0,sizeof(STRUCT_SPID_QA));`

Comment: Do not use memset on C++ classes (or structs which are classes with public members); read about constructors and destructors instead. For instance, you just zeroed all of a std::vector's bookkeeping information. While that may (or may not, I don't know!) just coincidentally be the data that is in an empty vector -- after all, the length is zero and the pointer value is irrelevant --, it is undefined behaviour. Your C background is appreciated but anti-paradigmatic in C++.

Comment: @LBran Forget everything about C programming *immediately* and get a decent book about C++.

Comment: @molbdnilo Honestly, it's not my choice to use C. I have to use these calls. :/

Comment: @LBran You should mention the `memset` call in an edit to your question as it is the reason things are going wrong. Not everyone is going to read this far down the comments.

Comment: @sjdowling How is `memset` the reason why things are going wrong? Can you please post an answer?

Comment: @LBran If you must use C, then you should write C code, not C++.

Comment: Okay.. any reason, @molbdnilo? Just curious.

Comment: @LBran the arguments to `memset` are 1. starting address of the memory to set, 2. value to set each byte to, 3. amount of bytes to set. so `memset(pQA,0,sizeof(STRUCT_SPID_QA))` sets every byte inside your `pQA` variable to 0, including vectors internal bookkeeping of its elements.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481654/memset-for-initialization-in-c

Comment: Thank you very much, guys! Will make some changes now and post back with results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `std::memset` call is (a) redundant, as

```
pQA = new STRUCT_SPID_QA(); // <---- note the parens
```

value-initializes the object, which initializes integers to `0` and pointers to `nullptr` here.

and (b) actually very wrong:

> If the object is not trivially-copyable (e.g., scalar, array, or a C-compatible struct), the behavior is undefined.

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset)

Your `_SPID_FQA_` contains non trivially copyable object of type `std::vector<Subject>`, which makes `_SPID_FQA_` non trivially copyable.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** firtly OPs didn't showed that he is using memset some where in his code that's y i gave this answer, as i thought this weired behavior is because of some problem in `clear` as mentioned in below links.

1) [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear): says that it    Invalidates any references, pointers, or iterators referring to contained elements. May invalidate any past-the-end iterators. 
Leaves the `capacity()` of the vector unchanged.

2) [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) says that : A reallocation is not guaranteed to happen, and the vector capacity is not guaranteed to change due to calling this function. A typical alternative that forces a reallocation is to use `swap` :

`vector<T>().swap(x);   // clear x reallocating`

but you can use this also:

```
int ResetFaceCollection()
{
    if (!pQA->people.empty())
    {
        pQA->people.erase(pQA->people.begin(),pQA->people.end());
    }
}
```

And check if it is giving any error?

here is the probably same environment and working fine with g++, clang, VC++ [link](http://ideone.com/aUOoux)

Comment: Thanks rupesh for your answer. The `erase()` call has the same outcome as `clear()` - debug assertion raised. The `swap()` does in fact work, but it seems a bit.. hacky?

Comment: yaa it is, but `erase` and `clear` should work though?

Comment: `clear()` does the same thing as `erase()`. Calling these methods gives me the error.

Comment: @LBran That is because your code is broken because you use `memset`. You need to fix that first. Anything else is cosmetic, unrelated to the failure, and futile.

Comment: Thanks, @juanchopanza. A few people have said that now but no explanation given. Can you please expand?

Comment: wooh.. you should have mentioned that memset thing brefore it self, i would have not done research on `clear`  and `erase` :P